# How do I reload the notes array after deleting one?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, onlongclicklistener

So im doing a notes app. It is really simple, and I am trying to add a function so that when I long click the note, I can delete it. It works, but the `notes` ArrayList doesnt refresh after deleting it. It is important to say that the functions is applied in an adapter. I have a function called `refresh` which, as its name suggest, refresh the activity when something like a new note is created. So after deleting the note, if I create a new note, the `refresh` function is called, and the previously deleted note disappears, but only if the reload function is called. However, for some reason I cant use the reload function inside the `onLongClickListener`
Can someone please help me.
Here is a copy of my code:

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NoteViewHolder> {
public static class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public LinearLayout containerView;
    public TextView nameTextView;

    public NoteViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.containerView = view.findViewById(R.id.note_row);
        this.nameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.note_row_name);

        this.containerView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View view) {
                final Note note = (Note) containerView.getTag();

                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.delete) {
                            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Note deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            MainActivity.database.noteDao().delete(note.id);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.delete_menu);
                popupMenu.show();

                return true;
            }
        });

        this.containerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = v.getContext();
                Note note = (Note) containerView.getTag();
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NoteActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", note.id);
                intent.putExtra("content", note.content);

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}

private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.note_row, parent, false);

    return new NoteViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NoteViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Note current = notes.get(position);
    holder.containerView.setTag(current);
    holder.nameTextView.setText(current.content);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return notes.size();
}

public void reload() {
    notes = MainActivity.database.noteDao().getAll();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, it is very simple.

**Make a small change**

```
recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(position);
```

It will works fine.

Comment: Where should I include this? In the main activity?

Comment: @Mulkur jangir please help

Comment: you should include this in adapter class

Comment: i write down recyclerViewAdapter , just for understanding.

Comment: Ok, but where? Cause i tried in the `onLongClick` and I cant do it. Im sorry to bother you, it is just that I really need to finish that @Mulkur jangir